# Pytest fixture inside class to execute only once

Tags: python, python-3.x, pytest

I need to create a class that uses a fixture from `conftest.py`, and this class has a fixture that I need to use only once per test session.

I have two test classes that depend on this class that has a fixture.

Sample code in `test_app.py`:

```
@pytest.mark.usefixtures("driver_get")
class TestBase:
    @pytest.fixture(scope="module", autouse=True)
    def set_up(self):
        # set up code.
        # web page will load if this fixture is called
        # uses self.driver, where driver was set in driver_get

class TestOne(TestBase):
    def test_1(self):
        # test code
        # uses self.driver also in the test

class TestTwo(TestBase):
    def test_2(self):
        # test code
        # uses self.driver also in the test
```

Sample code in `conftest.py` (follows https://dzone.com/articles/improve-your-selenium-webdriver-tests-with-pytest):

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def driver_get(request):
    from selenium import webdriver
    web_driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    session = request.node
    for item in session.items:
        cls = item.getparent(pytest.Class)
        setattr(cls.obj,"driver",web_driver)
    yield
    web_driver.close()
```

As you can see, `conftest.py` sets the driver as a class attribute, which is why I am applying the `driver_get` fixture to `class TestBase`, since I need to use the driver inside the class.

The problem is, once `TestOne` finishes, the web page will load again, and execute `TestTwo`, which means that the fixture `set_up` was executed again, which is not what I want (since I set `set_up` scope to module, so it should only really happen once).

I know there is a similar question asked here ([py.test method to be executed only once per run](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37100459/py-test-method-to-be-executed-only-once-per-run)), but the asker didn't have the constraint of needing `TestBase` to have a fixture applied to it as well.

I have thought of putting the fixture inside `conftest.py`, but I am not sure if it is possible given my constraint of the fixture needing to be inside a class, and executed only once.

Any help will be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

In your code, your `set_up` fixture which is module scope is called before your `TestBase` resolves the `driver_get` fixture. Because of this, at `set_up` trying `self.driver` will raise an `AttributeError: object has no attribute 'driver'`.

One quick way to fix this in your example code is to refer to the driver_get fixture in your module `set_up` fixture like so:

```
class TestBase:
    @pytest.fixture(scope="module", autouse=True)
    def set_up(self, driver_get): # <-------------
        self.driver.get("https://www.yahoo.com")
```

Another way to refer to fixtures is just by including the fixture name as an [argument](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/fixture.html).

Personally I am not a huge fan of the approach you copied from that blog of setting a class attribute on the request node. You'd get an IDE warning about referring to `self.driver`. To me, it would be clearer to yield the driver out of `driver_get` and then within the test classes either set it to `self` in a setup style fixture or use it directly. Similar to something below.

```
@pytest.fixture(scope="session")
def driver_get():
    from selenium import webdriver
    web_driver = webdriver.Chrome()
    yield web_driver
    web_driver.close()

class TestClass:
    @pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
    def setup(self, driver_get):
        self.driver = driver_get

    def test_something(self):
        self.driver.get("https://www.google.com")
```

But depending on what else needs to be setup, if you want to control it happening just once per session or module you would need to modify the approach a bit.